# How can I change default toast message color and background color in android?

Tags: android, android-toast

I want to create a toast message with background color is white and message color is black. My toast message is:

```
Toast.makeText(Logpage.this, "Please Give Feedback...", 3000).show();
```

I wanted to create it in another method not in `onCreate()`.

Comment: http://android-arsenal.com/free?sort=name use this site for custom toast

Comment: [Heads Up, Updates to toasts in Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31175657/4694013)

Answer (score 120):

You can create the custom toast message like below :

```
Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null);
toast.setView(view);
toast.show();
```

One textview you can put inside the layout file and give the background and textcolor as you want.

Also you can do the following which won't need the extra custom layout file :

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, R.string.string_message_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = toast.getView();
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_background);
TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
/*Here you can do anything with above textview like text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));*/
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
toast.show();
```

Comment: Thank you, this should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: Custom toast views are deprecated. Toasts constructed with Toast(Context) that haven't called setView(View) with a non-null view will return null

Comment: @Aydinozkan But in my answer, we have called setView(view) with non-null view, right ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller you are right, my mistake.

Comment: Google deprecated it from Android 11, now we can only use raw Toast!

Comment: Great solution that does not need a layout file. I having a little trouble changing the text color

Comment: No xml solution for the settings, like with a Dialog Box?

Comment: try {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            View view = toast.getView();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bk_toast_gradient_round);
            TextView textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            toast.show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 87):

**Change Toast Colours without any additional Layouts, 2018**

This is a very easy way I've found of changing the colour of the actual image background of the Toast as well as the text colour, it doesn't require any additional layouts or any XML changes:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
View view = toast.getView();

//Gets the actual oval background of the Toast then sets the colour filter
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOUR, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

//Gets the TextView from the Toast so it can be editted
TextView text = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
text.setTextColor(YOUR_TEXT_COLOUR);

toast.show();
```

Comment: perfect for my requirement.

Comment: view.setBackgroundColor(bgColor)
working fun in my case

Comment: I did not shaped as oval :( is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Custom toast views are deprecated. Toasts constructed with Toast(Context) that haven't called setView(View) with a non-null view will return null

Comment: What do you write if you want to use the color and text size resources in colors.xml and dimensions.xml respectively?

Comment: Deprecated for now

Comment: looks like setColorFilter() is deprecated, it crashes my android app when i run it in android 11(api30).

Answer (score 42):

### [Heads Up, Updates to toasts in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#toasts)

> Custom toasts from the background are blocked, Android 11 protects
> users by deprecating custom toast views. For security reasons and to
> maintain a good user experience, the system blocks toasts that contain
> custom views if those toasts are sent from the background by an app
> that targets Android 11.

[addCallback()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#addCallback(android.widget.Toast.Callback)) method added in Android R If you want to be notified when a toast (text or custom) appears or disappears.

The most important text in [toast API changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#text-toast-api-changes) that **for apps that target Android 11** the `getView()` method returns null when you access it, So, ensure to protect your apps from FATAL EXCEPTION, you know what I mean :)

---

> **You can customize android native toast by using following code**

```
/**
 * ShowToast
 */
public class ShowToast {
    public ShowToast(Context context, String info) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, Html.fromHtml("<font color='#e3f2fd' ><b>" + info + "</b></font>"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

**If you want to change the background you have to use custom layout in toast**

Comment: This is the best solution

Comment: How to change the background on Android 11 when setView is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/Toast#setview)

Comment: is there any way to set typeface?

Comment: Your link 'toast API changes' gives 404.

Comment: @androidguy Updated, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

To Change the default `Toast` Text Color and Background color Try Like this.

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Give Feedback...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
 View view = toast.getView();

 //To change the Background of Toast
 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);

 //Shadow of the Of the Text Color
 text.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
 text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
 text.setTextSize(Integer.valueOf(getResources().getString(R.string.text_size)));
 toast.show();
```

Comment: @Saranya Whats the error You got or the Toast Colors are not changing.

Comment: Custom toast views are deprecated. Toasts constructed with Toast(Context) that haven't called setView(View) with a non-null view will return null

Comment: What do you write if you want to use the color and text size resources in colors.xml and dimensions.xml respectively?

Answer (score 12):

use this way

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);   
toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F6AE2D"));
toast.show();
```

Comment: After changing the background color and text color, toast shape changed to rectangle. Why is this happening ?? Why is the default ellipse shape of toast is not retained after changing colors ??

Comment: After changer color the Toast  become squire. Why?

Comment: Custom toast views are deprecated. Toasts constructed with Toast(Context) that haven't called setView(View) with a non-null view will return null

Comment: Not work in Android11

Answer (score 7):

Create a layout file toast.xml as to how your toast should look as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a custom toast."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To show the toast in the java file put the below code:

```
public void showCustomAlert()
    {         
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        // Create layout inflator object to inflate toast.xml file
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        // Call toast.xml file for toast layout 
        View toastView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, null);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toastView.setView(toast);

        // Set layout to toast 
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,
                0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();         
    }
```

Comment: how come 2 variables with same anem `toast`

Answer (score 6):

To keep round corners

```
val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
toast.view.background.setTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, android.R.color.darker_gray))
toast.show()
```

Comment: This requires API level 21.

Answer (score 5):

```
Toast toast=   Toast.makeText(YOUR ACTIVITY NAME ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
View view =toast.getView();
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); //any color your want 
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 5):

Change default toast message color and background color in JAVA. You can change toast message color and background color this way..

```
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Signin button is clicked.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        View view =toast.getView();
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        TextView toastMessage = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        toastMessage.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        toast.show();
```

Just change toast text color this way..

```
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signup button is clicked.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        TextView toastMessage=(TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        toastMessage.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        toast.show();
```

Comment: After changing the background color and text color, toast shape changed to rectangle. Why is this happening ?? Why is the default ellipse shape of toast is not retained after changing colors ??

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin Version:

```
 val toast = Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.back_again), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
 val view = toast.view
 view.background.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
 toast.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin Version:**

```
val toast:Toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your name !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
val view = toast.view
view?.background?.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
toast.show()
```

Comment: Not work in Android11

Answer (score 1):

```
static void CustomToast(Context context, String text, int duration,
                                    @Nullable Integer backgroundColor,
                                    @Nullable Integer textColor){
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(context,text,duration);
        if (backgroundColor != null)
            t.getView()
                    .setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(backgroundColor));
        if (textColor != null)
            ((TextView)t.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message))
                    .setTextColor(textColor);
        t.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @AndroidKiller's answer, you can also set the `gravity` and a custom `TextView` among other things like so:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(resID), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );        
View toastView = li.inflate(R.layout.toast_hint_layout, null);
TextView text = (TextView) toastView.findViewById(R.id.hint_text_tv);
text.setText(resID);
toast.setView(toastView);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toastView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toast_9_patch);          
toast.show();
```

Note, your background drawable should be a [nine-patch PNG](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

You can even put an `ImageView`, and multiple `TextView`s in with XML like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_root"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lightbulb"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hint_text_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ccc"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hint_text_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(disable hints in preferences)"
            android:textColor="#555"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by setting the background color filter color and finding the toast resource ID and setting the text color.

[Android.Graphics.Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color)

```
    /// <summary> Creates and displays a toast with the given text. </summary>
    public void Show(string message)
    {
        // Create the toast.
        Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Long);

        // Set the background color.
        Android.Graphics.Color c = new Android.Graphics.Color(122, 193, 66, 255);
        Android.Graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter CMF = new Android.Graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[]
            {
                0,0,0,0,(float)c.R,
                0,0,0,0,(float)c.G,
                0,0,0,0,(float)c.B,
                0,0,0,1,0
            });
        toast.View.Background.SetColorFilter(CMF);

        // Set the text color.
        toast.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Message).SetTextColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(0, 55, 103, 255));

        // Display the toast.
        toast.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short java code that keeps the **round** shape:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.getView().setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
toast.show();
```

Comment: Not work in Android11

Answer (score 0):

Well here you can update the existing view of the toast class
because setting new background would remove rounded border and all you want is changing background color and text color without changing toast background decoration

```
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        TextView textView = toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setTextSize(25);
        toast.getView().getBackground().clearColorFilter();
        toast.getView().getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        toast.show();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations.