# How too add toast color on Android

Tags: android, android-toast

Trying too figure of how too add color too a toast

I tried and I made a regular toast but I'm wanting one with color and effects if possible.

Comment: A simple google search: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-a-custom-styled-toast-in-android-using-kotlin/

Comment: That's not working at least for the toast I made?

Comment: @javdromero The point is that regular toasts can't do that and one has to roll out custom system to (partially) mimic the functionality. Posting a sole link isn't very helpful in clearing out this fundamental assumption. Especially as the "article" is just some code with no explanations at all. It doesn't even explain that it won't show when your app is in the background, like a regular toast will.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about?

Comment: @Agent_L then the main error in this case is assuming, and we should let the author explain on detail since it seems he/she has minimal experience on android

Comment: Okay I will wait for that.

Comment: You are the author of this question @RileyPQ1462 , we are the ones waiting

Comment: People put color on their I just want know how I can do mine 

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the Toast color cannot be customised anymore.

The documentation says:
*Custom toast views are deprecated. Apps can create a standard text toast with the makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) method, or use a Snackbar when in the foreground. Starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES.R, apps targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES.R or higher that are in the background will not have custom toast views displayed.*

Depending on your use case, look for other components like Snackbars. For this you can do some customisation: https://m2.material.io/components/snackbars/android

Comment: I don't know how make those or what too click on?

Comment: Also I saw someone post yesterday with a colored?

Comment: For Snackbar I added the documentation, it's in the link. About being colored, it was indeed possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175601/how-can-i-change-default-toast-message-color-and-background-color-in-android - but it's now deprecated. Also Toast are intended to be a simple feedback about an operation in a small popup, very limited and less configurations, so my advice would be to either rethink on your design / use another component, instead of doing something trickier.

Comment: I tried them and it say unsupported on all lines how do I fix?

Comment: What do I do about it?